# Write/ink on anything when recording the screen

Tags: windows-8, screen-recording, drawing, tablet

Explanation of what I'm looking for:

- Real time drawing/inking with stylus over what you are recording on the screen
- Palm rejection<sup>*</sup>
- Pressure sensitivity preferable

I use a Windows 8.1 laptop (ThinkPad Yoga generation 1) and a Wacom EMR pen.

---

What happens when I try [the program ShowMore mentioned in this answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/30640/):

- Attempting to draw on top of a YouTube video will just click the video and pause it
- At least when I tried it, my penstrokes with my stylus only created straight lines
- It's not inking (there's a specific definition for inking though I'm not sure what it is but think like OneNote's inking for example)

<sup>* Palm rejection refers to a touch screen's ability to "reject" or ignore the presence of a palm during the process of drawing or signature capture. Palm rejection capabilities allows for accurate on-screen drawing and for capturing of a more accurate signature.</sup>

Comment: You're almost looking for "sports teleprompter" behavior...  where you can do the play-by-play on a live screen without interrupting it.

Comment: What program would be my best bet? This thread isn't over- when I try to write with my digitizer using the program below, it does not work - the program keeps thinking I'm trying to draw a line from some point far off the screen instead of pen strokes. And it is not inking

Answer (score 1):

So your requirements are:

1. Record screen with your voice in.
2. Draw in the video in real-time.

As far as I'm concerned, the online recorder [**ShowMore**](http://showmore.com/) can meet your needs.

It can record the screen with microphone sound, and in the meanwhile, during recording, there is a pen icon on the bottom toolbar, which you can use to draw lines, arrows and texts in the video in real time.

For your convenience, I attached this screenshot. :)

[image: Interface of ShowMore]

Comment: When I tried it: no palm rejection, can only draw straight lines with the paint brush for some reason. If I try drawing on top of a youtube video, I will end up clicking the video instead and pausing it.

Comment: That's strange. The paint brush works fine on my computer, just like in the screenshot. The text input does have a little bug (sometimes pause video, other options won't). You can ask their support service for solving the problems.